# Receive full data from asynchronous socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networking

I have this code (see below) that is widely inspired from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx
The code is supposed to get the full request from a client stored into a buffer, and all of this is done in an asynchronous context.
note that the code below is called the first time using :
`state.SourceSocket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFromClient), state);`

```
    private static void ReceiveFromClient(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var state = result.AsyncState as State;
        try
        {
            var bytesRead = state.SourceSocket.EndReceive(result);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                // here I try to get some more data if needed
                state.SourceSocket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFromClient), state);
                // this stands for _socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, callback, state);

            }
            else if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Now sending the received message");
                state.bufferString = state.sb.ToString();
                state.DestinationSocket.BeginSend(new AsyncCallback(SendToRemote), state);
            }
        }
        // uninteresting catch block
    }
```

Here is the `State` class just for the sake of clarity

```
public class State
{
    public Socket SourceSocket { get; private set; }
    public Socket DestinationSocket { get; private set; }

    public int BufferSize;
    public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }
    public string bufferString;
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public State(Socket source, Socket destination, int bufferSize)
    {
        SourceSocket = source;
        DestinationSocket = destination;
        Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        BufferSize = bufferSize;
    }
}
```

The problem is the following :
The first call to `ReceiveFromClient` seem to work fine, I get some data, but when I call `BeginReceive`the second time nothing at all is happening, I don't even enter the callback again.
Note that this might be a beginner mistake as it's my first time dealing with c# application.

Comment: The misconception is, if `bytesRead == 0` means that the socket is disconnected. So you can't wait until no bytes are left. If you receive all bytes in one read, you have to fill the `state.bufferString = state.sb.ToString();` The problem is.. TCP is a streaming protocol, so you need to specify something that the packet/message is finished. Most protocols will send a header that specifies the data length.  `[header(data.length)][data][header(data.length)][data]`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen you need to be careful with that assertion -  IIRC you can do zero-length async reads which can be useful to do a zero-cost "await there being some data"; i.e. "if no data, do a zero length read, which will callback when there is *something*, then I can re-assess what to do next"

Comment: @MarcGravell Never heard of it. So It's something like an async `DataAvailable`. Which implies to keep track on how many bytes requested to check if it is a disconnect.

Comment: I effectively receive the whole request on the first read in this case, but this will not always be true. But the idea of calling again beginRead like this comes from the msdn documentation itself, so I don't know..

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yep, exactly that; very useful when you have a lot of sockets to service and you don't want to allocate lots of buffers or have to track lots of fragments of a single shared buffer - you can just say "read me zero bytes and get back to me when you've done that"

Comment: @MarcGravell Great method for implementing bufferpool. Thanks for this tip. Meaning that you will read 0 bytes into a reused `static byte[0]`.

Comment: @Jeroen indeed - although note that once you've read once, you can leave the previous buffer and just specify 0 bytes from it. There is some overhead that happens when you swap the buffer instance, so you can avoid that. And it doesn't matter if you've already handed the buffer to another caller, because you're *reading zero bytes*